# Unable to retrieve json output from python to php

Tags: php, python, html, json

I am trying to create a webpage that takes in a file and sends the file to a python program, manipulates it and sends the results back to php and then displayed back to the webpage.

For now, I am showing the code as a webpage that takes in a file, sends it to python, gets the file name, sends it back to php and prints it in the webpage. the php to python connection is via json. I am not able to get the results back to my webpage or my php page.

Here are the codes:

test.html

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) 
    {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
 else 
    {
        $filepath=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $myFile=$filepath;
        $result = shell_exec('C:\\Python33\\python C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pathovcf\\test.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($myFile)));
        $resultData = json_decode($result, true);
        echo $resultData;
    }
?>
```

test.py

```
import os
import sys
import json
import re
filepath=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print(json.dumps(filepath))
```

Any idea where I am making mistakes?

Comment: So what, if anything, happens when you run the program? And what is `$myfile = $filepath` supposed to achieve? Is PHP running in [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php)?

Comment: $myfile = $filepath was just a check. How do i check if php is running in safe mode or not?

Comment: @holdenweb: found it. its not running in safe mode. safe mode is off

Comment: Don't ask me, I'm a Python programmer. However you might try adding

    `print(filepath, file=sys.stderr)`

before the last line of your Python program. This should (I hope) make the output appear in your web server log.

Comment: There are lots of moving parts. Take them apart and test them one by one. 1) Does `echo "hello"` work in PHP? 2) Does `echo shell_exec('cmd /c dir')` work? 3) Simplify your python program to one line: `print("hello!")`. Does your PHP script work with that simple Python program? 4) Does your Python program work isolated from the PHP? Can you run it from the command prompt? 5) Does the system work if you comment out `json_decode`?

Comment: Consider the myriad of reasons detailed on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for shell_exec() to fail.

Comment: "*I am not able to get the results back*". That describes what **doesn't** happen. Now tell us what **does** happen. Do you get an error message? A blank screen? Does the web browser's icon spin in a wait indication? Is there an entry in your web server's log?

Comment: Its a blank screen. The page loads but its an empty page.